# How to display multiple mongoose search results in expressjs

Tags: node.js, model-view-controller, express, mongoose

I'm working to create an MVC on top of expressjs, in order to learn express. I am having trouble between the model and view. The Git repo exists [here](https://github.com/fogonthedowns/capricorn).

I would like to display a list of blog posts. I'm using a custom jasmine view, in conjunction with mongoose and expressjs. I have no idea how to return the list of posts from the query (find({}) and transfer that object to the view or work with those posts in jasmine once I have them.

The best idea I had to access this information in my view was through [res.locals](http://expressjs.com/api.html#res.locals), but it doesn't seem to work.

```
// read
app.get('/', function(req, res){
  Blog.find({},function(err, records){
    res.locals.posts = records
    // res.send(records);
    records.forEach(function(record){
      console.log(record["body"])
    });
  });

  res.render("home.jade", {online:req.online.length + ' users online', posts:VARIABLE_I_AM_UNCLEAR_ABOUT});
});
```

I can see body text in my console.log, so its clear I have json blog posts. Furthermore I can return JSON with res.send(records). I would like access to those records, so I can style those in my view with jasmine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just move the `render` to the location where you tried `send`:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res){
  Blog.find({},function(err, records){
    res.render("home.jade", {
      online : req.online.length + ' users online',
      posts  : records
    });
  });
});
```

`Blog.find()` is asynchronous, so the callback function will get called only when the results are sent back from the database. In your original situation, you rendered the template without first waiting for the results.

Comment: Thank you! I spent an hour or so on this